# Django ORM: wrapper for model objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I am looking for some way to define some wrapper that is called before i call to `Model.objects.all()`.

I want whenever i call, `Model.objects` it call my method (wrapper) and then return the objects back to the query.

Lets take an example:

```
MyModel.objcts.filter(name="Jack")
```

Wrapper:

```
def mymodelWrapper(self):
    return self.objects.annotate(size=Sum('id', field='order_size_weight*requested_selling_price'))
```

I want to run annotate in the background and also want to apply the filter.
I Know what i want to achieve, its the code i am looking for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is perfectly doable with Django by using a [custom model manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance):

```
class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(MyModelManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(size=Sum('id', field='order_size_weight*requested_selling_price'))


class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyModelManager()

    # fields
```

Also see other similar topics:

- [Is it possible to override .objects on a django model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762524/is-it-possible-to-override-objects-on-a-django-model)
- [Override djangos's object.all() with the request data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487463/override-djangoss-object-all-with-the-request-data)
- [Django custom model managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115009/django-custom-model-managers)

Comment: Just moving on, I can use `COALESCE` with select extra, which gives me first non null value. is there any way to use the same in annotate functions?

Comment: @Jack I think this can be a separate legitimate Stackoverflow question - more people could help you as opposed to using comments. Thank you.